# Uses of definite article before comparative degree

Tags: definite-articles, comparatives, comparisons

Here are two sentences from a grammar book:

> "He is the stronger of the two."

> "Reena is smarter than any other student of her class."

In the first sentence, the definite article (*the*) was used before the comparative degree. But in the second, why was '*the*' was not used before 'smarter,' even though it is also in the comparative degree?

Comment: You expect "the smarter than any ..."? That comparative isn't a noun.

Comment: He is the stronger [man] of the two. You could use an article in the other too: Reena is a smarter person than any other student in her class.

Comment: The OP has obviously heard the rule about using _the_ in superlatives, and is now finding them in other similar constructions. Articles pervade English, and there aren't any good rules for using them. You hafta make a lot of mistakes.

Comment: When a comparative (or superlative) is modified by "the", it normally has an _of_ PP as its complement, as in your first example. By contrast, the preposition "than" has a reduced comparative clause as complement, and here the comparative “smarter” cannot be modified by “the”.

Comment: Also, standalone 'He is stronger.' is correct, but if two people have already been mentioned, 'He is the stronger.' is also correct.

Comment: @BillJ the *of* PP is sometimes elided. "Be the better man."

Comment: Are you aware of our sister site, English Language Learners. In my opinion — and my reading of the description of the scope of this site that you have posted on —  you should be posting there, not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first sentence, "the stronger" is a nominal phrase. (You could consider "stronger" a nominalized adjective, or you could consider some noun, such as "person", to be understood at the end of that phrase.) It functions as a predicate nominative.

In your second sentence, inserting "the" would also create a nominal phrase, and it could also function as a predicate nominative. However, "than" typically requires an adjectival or adverbial for comparison, not a nominal.<sup>1</sup> Thus, inserting "the" in your second sentence produces a nongrammatical construction. (This is similar to what BillJ wrote in a comment with different terminology.)

---

<sup>1</sup> There are exceptions, such as "she is a better person than I". However, those exceptions wouldn't apply here.