# "The" together with comparative degree

Tags: idioms, word-usage

For me English is the second language, so when I was taught about the comparison degrees, there were positive (normal), comparative (beyond normal) and superlative (taken to the extreme) degrees of adjestives. The latter comes with the article "the", which I guess is justified by the uniquenes of the global maximum (Set theory 101).

For this reason, I'm quite surprised every time I hear about cases when the comparative degree is combined with "the", for example "The Elder Scrolls" as in the game series, or "The Elder" as in John Wick 3, 4. Does it have to deal with the legacy of the language, meaning there are few examples (or maybe "the elder" is the only one), or is that a common rule I was not taught?

Comment: I'm looking through the other questions on comparatives here, but it's no great mystery: "bigger dogs" means some indefinite dogs that are bigger than average, while "the bigger dogs" refers to specific dogs that are bigger, e.g. those in a specific dog park that are bigger than the others, "the bigger dogs are stealing food from the smaller dogs".

Comment: "The" can certainly be used with comparison in many situations. Off the top of my head, examples like "the better option", the older brother" etc. As @StuartF says, it seems to depend on whether or not you have a specific subject.

Comment: Please don't create answers in comments. Answers go in the answer box.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uses of definite article before comparative degree](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/605606/uses-of-definite-article-before-comparative-degree) // Here, whatever the etymological reasoning and overall justification, 'Elder Scrolls' must be seen as a compound noun, a single lexeme. Compare 'the Greater Antilles', 'the Higher Atlas', 'the lesser whitethroat [is a fairly secretive warbler]'....

Comment: I'm not familiar with your examples, but don't forget that _elder_ can also be a noun.

Comment: The comparative form of an adjective is used instead of the superlative when only two things are involved. In a race between two people the winner is the faster runner. The word *fastest* is used when three or more are involved. This should have been an answer but the question has been closed as a duplicate of another closed question. This comment/answer fits better here than with the duplicate question,

Comment: @Peter “The better students realised that the question was a red herring”